# QGraphicsItem no such file

Tags: c++, qt

There are 2 lib in project (`TEMPLATE = lib` in .pro file) lib1 and lib2.
And before today lib1 depend on lib2:

`LIBS += -llib2` in lib1.pro

also macros was defined and used in class i want to import

`#if defined(LIB2_BUILD)
 #define LIB2_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
 #else
 #define LIB2_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
 #endif`

all was fine, but now i need to use some class from lib1 in lib2.

I done:

`LIBS += -llib1` in lib2.pro

and define `EXPORT` masroc for second lib and use it for class wich I want to use in lib2.

but when I add `#include "../lib1/header.h"` I get error

`error: QGraphicsItem: No such file or directory #include <QGraphicsItem>`

maybe I forget anything?
sorry, if my description of problem is bad.

**UPD**

If I delete `#include "../lib1/header.h"` it compile and work.

**UPD2**

I found that I can't include `<QGraphicsItem>` in file from lib2 - same error.

Now I have in .pro file `QT += core widgets gui`, but before I do this it was:

`QT += core widgets
 QT -= gui`

I run qmake and rebuild project. Nothing change.

**SOLUTION**

problem was in other libraries which use lib2 and didn't have `QT += gui`

Comment: `QT += gui` in both pro-files?

Comment: yes, in both pro-files

Comment: `QT += widgets` if you are using Qt5, you didn't specify

Comment: `QT += core widgets gui` in both (i'm using Qt 5.3)

Comment: oh.. sorry, I was careless and didn't read whole compiler output.
U're right, but I need to add this to all lib's which use lib2.